# Storing custom game state data on a player

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

Hi guys I have the array where are stored all alive players. I want to check if all of them has specific metadata. Something like:

```java
Player dead = event.getEntity().getPlayer();
PLAYING.remove(dead);
SPECTATORS.add(dead);
if (all PLAYING.hasMetaData("murder"){
    Bukkit.broadcastMessage("Murders have won the game!");
}
```

Btw event is PlayerDeathEvent

Answer (score 3):

[`Player`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/entity/Player.html) extends [`Metadatable`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/metadata/Metadatable.html), so you can do something like this:

```java
PlayerType playerType = PlayerType.MURDERER;
player.setMetadata("PLAYER_TYPE_KEY", new FixedMetadataValue(yourPluginInstance, playerType));
```

Then check and fetch it:

```java
if(player.hasMetadata("PLAYER_TYPE_KEY")) {
   PlayerType playerType = (PlayerType) player.getMetadata("PLAYER_TYPE_KEY").get(0).value();
   if(playerType == PlayerType.MURDERER)
        ...
}
```

I've made up the "PlayerType" enum, but you could store whatever value you wanted. You must add extra checks to ensure index zero exists and is not null.

However, you may wish to consider creating a data object to represent the state of your player because you're already storing them in a list. For example, you could have something like this:

```java
public class PlayerGameState {
    private final PlayerType playerType;
    private boolean isDead;
    private boolean isSpectating;
    // ... more state data

    public PlayerGameState() {
        this.playerType = PlayerType.PLAYER;
    }

    public PlayerGameState(PlayerType playerType) {
        this.playerType = playerType;
    }

    // ... getters & setters
    public void setIsDead(boolean isDead) {
        this.isDead = isDead;
    }
}
```

And then you could store their state in a map:

```
private Map<UUID, PlayerGameState> playerStateMap = new HashMap<>();

...

//Example methods (minimal & no data integrity checks)

public void addPlayerToGame(Player player) {
    playerStateMap.put(player.getUniqueId(), PlayerGameState::new);
}

@EventHandler
public void onDeath(PlayerDeathEvent event) {
    PlayerGameState state = PlayerGameState.get(event.getPlayer().getUniqueId());
    if(state.getPlayerType() == PlayerType.MURDERER)
        ...
}
```

This approach would avoid having multiple lists to represent if your players are playing, spectating and in which capacity they're playing (plus whatever else makes up their state).

Comment: According to my IDE PlayerType does not exist
(I only use Bukkit API)

Comment: @vitekform As I mentioned in my answer, I made up `PlayerType`. It would be an enum that contains the various roles/types that your players may become.

Comment: Oh sorry then. :)